# ICS - Automatically syncing all exchange account folders

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, exchange, active-sync

The standard e-mail client of ICS offers greater flexibility in choosing the sync. settings for individual folders of an exchange account.  I use an exchange server for my e-mail and use several sub folders on a regular basis.  Is there anyway for me to set that all folders automatically sync using the account defaults (push at all times)?  As it stands, I have to individually change the sync options for each individual folder by entering it and changing the settings.  This is very time consuming and something I'm keen to avoid in the future with new folders.

Many thanks,
Rich